# Listening to many JTextFields and calculate value sum in a Row

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, documentlistener

I have an application that gets input from user;
it has 8 rows of `JTextFields` with 3 columns:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Field 1-1 | Field 1-2 | Field 1-3 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Field 2-1 | Field 2-2 | Field 2-3 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Field 3-1 | Field 3-2 | Field 3-3 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

In each row while user changes first or second field the sum of new values must be written in third field.
For example when user changes Filed 1-1 & Field 1-2 sum of them must be calculated and shown in Field 1-3 and so on for other rows.
I wrote a Class that implements `DocumentListener` and and named it `listenerClass` & called `.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new listenerClass)` for all of `JTextFields` in column 1 & 2 ;
Now in `listenerClass` I need to know which `JTextField` called `listenerClass` to be able determine wich fields must be added and result must be written in which `JTextField`.

How Can I find out which `JTextField` called `DocumentListener` ?
Is there any better method to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options here:

- brute force: just one listener instance that will compute 8 sums and update 8 text fields
- smart: pass to your listener class constructor 3 text fields and then instantiate a differente listener for each row

Answer (score 2):

put a property with [putClientProperty](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#putClientProperty%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) method on each JTextField. You can use that property as an id, and get it back inside the listener.
For example:

```
JTextField 1_1 = new JTextField();
1_1.putClientProperty("id", "1_1");
```

EDIT:
Sorry, I was forgetting that you don't have a reference to source object inside listener. SO it's better also do:

```
JTextField 1_1 = new JTextField();
1_1.getDocument.putProperty("source", 1_1);
```

the from inside the listener you can do:

```
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {

         //source
         Object source = documentEvent.getDocument().getProperty("source");
         if (source instanceof JTextField){
             JTextField field = (JTextField)source;
             String id = field.getClientProperty("id");
         }
}
```

I asked a similar question some months ago: have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218731/how-to-find-source-component-that-generated-a-documentevent).

Answer (score 2):

consider using [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) instead of plenty of [JTextFields or JFormattedTextFields](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) and listening by some of [Listeners](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html)

[image]

from code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableProcessing extends JFrame implements TableModelListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTable table;

    public TableProcessing() {
        String[] columnNames = {"Item", "Quantity", "Price", "Cost"};
        Object[][] data = {
            {"Bread", new Integer(1), new Double(1.11), new Double(1.11)},
            {"Milk", new Integer(1), new Double(2.22), new Double(2.22)},
            {"Tea", new Integer(1), new Double(3.33), new Double(3.33)},
            {"Cofee", new Integer(1), new Double(4.44), new Double(4.44)}
        };
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        model.addTableModelListener(this);
        table = new JTable(model) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToModel(column);
                return (modelColumn == 3) ? false : true;
            }
        };
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(150, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getSource());
        if (e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE) {
            int row = e.getFirstRow();
            int column = e.getColumn();
            if (column == 1 || column == 2) {
                TableModel model = table.getModel();
                int quantity = ((Integer) model.getValueAt(row, 1)).intValue();
                double price = ((Double) model.getValueAt(row, 2)).doubleValue();
                Double value = new Double(quantity * price);
                model.setValueAt(value, row, 3);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TableProcessing frame = new TableProcessing();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if one doesn't use `JTable`, this example shows the benefit of using a [separate model](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/architecture/#separable).

Answer (score 1):

Use `yourTextField.setName("Alice")`, then in your DocumentListener implementation retrieve the name with with `getName()` and check for "Alice".

These methods belong to the `java.awt.Component` class. Every swing JComponent extends from it.